WSO2 API Manager - Identity Server as Key Manager Refresh Token Error When Issuing a New Access Token
I am using wso2am-4.1.0 and I have setup wso2is-5.11.0 as the Key Manager.
I tried invoking the token endpoint using the refresh_token grant type as per the below curl.
curl -k -d "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<refresh_token>" -H "Authorization: Basic <Base64Encoded(Client_Id:Client_Secret)>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
However, I'm getting a 500 error from the server. In the Identity Server log, the following exception could be observed.
ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/oauth2].[OAuth2Endpoints]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [OAuth2Endpoints] in context with path [/oauth2] threw exception org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.model.RefreshTokenValidationDataDO.getAccessTokenIssuedTime()Ljava/sql/Timestamp;
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:296)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:215)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.filter.AuthorizationHeaderFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationHeaderFilter.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.model.RefreshTokenValidationDataDO.getAccessTokenIssuedTime()Ljava/sql/Timestamp;
        at org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor.onPostTokenRenewal(ApimOauthEventInterceptor.java:207)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.data.publisher.oauth.OAuthInterceptorHandlerProxy.onPostTokenRenewal(OAuthInterceptorHandlerProxy.java:113)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.triggerPostListeners(AccessTokenIssuer.java:493)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.issue(AccessTokenIssuer.java:327)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service.issueAccessToken(OAuth2Service.java:257)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:297)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:122)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor171.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        ... 57 more

I followed the official documentation mentioned below to setup the cluster.
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/
A direction to resolve this issue is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

RefreshTokenValidationDataDO class in identity-inbound-auth-oauth version 6.4.11 is missing the methods to retrieve token metadata. You can clone this repository add the missing functionality.

Clone the repository and checkout the version 6.4.11
Apply the fix from the pull request
Build the project with maven

 mvn clean install


Replace the <IS_HOME>/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth-6.4.11.jar file in your IS deployment with the newly built jar file from the components/org.wso2.carbon.oauth/target directory of the repo.

This issue is already fixed for subscription customers.

Thanks. Can you please let me know the location of the jar file? I cannot find it inside the target folder.

I found the jar file inside the components/org.wso2.carbon.oauth/target directory and I copied it a replaced the existing jar file inside the repository/components/plugins directory. However, I'm receiving this error now and the IS fails to startup.
[] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat} - error while parsing xml stream org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 93; Error at line [37] column [93]: [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

@LilanMihiranga Did you apply the fix for all 3 files in the PR? Does it say which class is not found?

The class which is not found is org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve. What I did was

git clone https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth.git
cd identity-inbound-auth-oauth
git checkout v6.4.11
git fetch origin pull/1733/head:pr-1733
git checkout pr-1733
Disable style checking from the pom.xml
mvn clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip -X


@LilanMihiranga Instead of checking out and building the PR, try manually applying the changes in the PR on 6.4.11 version

I applied the changes manually this time on all 3 files, built the jar file and replaced it with the existing one. But I still get the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve error and the IS fails to startup.

Is there a more recent fix for this? building that entire repository with correct java/maven versions is not straightforward at all. And even after building it, the version number is different and many users are reporting problems with identity server startup. This bug should be considered critical.
